# Selenium Getting all rows

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying get all rows but ı am getting every time error .

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


url = "https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/"

driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(30)


list = []

new_text=browser.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[@id='ranks']/tbody"))
for text in new_text:
   list.append(text.text)
   print(list)
```

I am using `time.sleep` because in there have a captha ı am manually logining and opening Highscore page. But ı don't know why not working my codes .

//*[@id="ranks"] this is xpath the table - //*[@id="ranks"]/tbody

Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide a link to that page?

Comment: Yes sir , ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=highscore

Comment: Thanks, but I need a username with password too.. Can you provide that?

Comment: What rows you are referring to? Can you provide more details please.

Comment: But in there have ogame captha not google captha or hcaptha :/ because ı writed time.sleep user can login manually and open page.

Comment: I can't see any captcha. Also don't see the Highscore page

Comment: Ah, OK, there was catcha. But still don't see the Highscore page

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/reb32du6 @Osama Naveed

Comment: You need click the play button

Comment: You want to get the list of servers?

Comment: No ı want get in highscore page usernames and points

Comment: Share the link of highscore page

Comment: ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=highscore but in there have subdomain in every server difrent ı am playing in en server because my link s172-en.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=highscore

Comment: Got it. Let me try.

Comment: @W3gor Please accept my answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: But not working on chrome :/

Comment: What is the error you are getting and which part of the code is causing the error?

Comment: I sloved time.sleep(1) need add :)) thank you , but not parsing from highscore page

Comment: @W3gor Please edit your question with the issue you are facing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
# Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # using beautifulsoup to parse the ranking
import time

email = '' # set your account email here
password = '' # set your account password here

url = "https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/"

driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(url)

# No need for that. You can use implicit waits from selenium
time.sleep(30)

# click on login tab
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Log in']").click()

# locate email field and set email
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys(email)

# locate password field and set password
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password)

# locate and click on login button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p//button//span[text()='Log in']").click()

# locate and click on play button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='joinGame']//a//button//span[text()='Play']").click()

# locate and start the first server from the list
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rt-td action-cell']//button//span[text()='Start']").click()

# At this stage new window will open. Shift to the newly opened tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# locate and click on "Highscore tab"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Highscore']").click()

# At this stage a table will appear containing ranks.
# get ranks table
ranks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='ranks']//tbody")

# parsing ranks with beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(ranks.text)

span = 2
ranking = soup.find('p').text.split("\n")
parsed_ranking = [" ".join(ranking[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(ranking), span)]

final_ranking = list()
for r in parsed_ranking:
    splitted_r = " ".join(r.split())
    splitted_r = splitted_r.split(' ')
    rank = {
        'position': splitted_r[0],
        'player_name': f"{splitted_r[2] if not splitted_r[2].startswith(' ') else ''} {splitted_r[3] if not splitted_r[3].__contains__('(') else ''}".strip(),
        'points': splitted_r[-1]
    }
    final_ranking.append(rank)
```

At this stage you will have rankings in list like this:

```js
[{'position': '501', 'player_name': 'Geologist Uranus', 'points': '27.847'},
 {'position': '502', 'player_name': 'Technocrat Auriga', 'points': '27.192'},
 {'position': '503', 'player_name': 'President Phoenix', 'points': '27.032'},
 {'position': '504', 'player_name': '[AMA] Commander', 'points': '26.865'},
 {'position': '505', 'player_name': 'Kampfdackel157', 'points': '26.397'},
 {'position': '506', 'player_name': 'Vice Uriel', 'points': '25.482'},
 {'position': '507', 'player_name': 'Satansmight', 'points': '24.502'},
 {'position': '508', 'player_name': 'Geologist...', 'points': '22.929'},
 {'position': '509', 'player_name': 'Emperor Cupid', 'points': '22.919'},
 {'position': '510', 'player_name': 'Lieutenan...', 'points': '21.278'},
 {'position': '511', 'player_name': 'Engineer Orb', 'points': '20.998'},
 {'position': '512', 'player_name': 'PrinceOfSaiyans', 'points': '20.064'},
 {'position': '513', 'player_name': 'IAmGebber', 'points': '19.746'},
 {'position': '514', 'player_name': 'Viceregent Pallas', 'points': '18.965'},
 {'position': '515', 'player_name': '[OR1] Fiari', 'points': '18.873'},
 {'position': '516', 'player_name': 'Mogul Spacewalk', 'points': '18.151'},
 {'position': '517', 'player_name': 'Czar Kale', 'points': '17.089'},
 {'position': '518', 'player_name': '[KniEng] Engineer', 'points': '16.633'},
 {'position': '519', 'player_name': 'Hkmikej', 'points': '16.245'},
 {'position': '520', 'player_name': 'Governor Titan', 'points': '15.960'},
 {'position': '521', 'player_name': 'Technocrat Helio', 'points': '15.528'},
 {'position': '522', 'player_name': 'Admiral Pathfinder', 'points': '15.248'},
 {'position': '523', 'player_name': '[UFP] General', 'points': '14.902'},
 {'position': '524', 'player_name': 'Thomyb', 'points': '14.528'},
 {'position': '525', 'player_name': 'Crom Gruach', 'points': '13.705'},
 {'position': '526', 'player_name': 'Bhaal', 'points': '12.933'},
 {'position': '527', 'player_name': 'Captain Davida', 'points': '12.407'},
 {'position': '528', 'player_name': '[smerf] Senator', 'points': '12.063'},
 {'position': '529', 'player_name': '[AMA] Mogul', 'points': '11.485'},
 {'position': '530', 'player_name': 'Procurator Polaris', 'points': '10.985'},
 {'position': '531', 'player_name': 'Geologist Nekkar', 'points': '10.807'},
 {'position': '532', 'player_name': 'Viceregent Lambda', 'points': '10.735'},
 {'position': '533', 'player_name': 'Commander Kuma', 'points': '10.523'},
 {'position': '534', 'player_name': 'Director Sol', 'points': '9.922'},
 {'position': '535', 'player_name': 'Sizan', 'points': '9.865'},
 {'position': '536', 'player_name': 'KyKy_EnTa', 'points': '9.567'},
 {'position': '537', 'player_name': '[SEX] LLamaFlorian', 'points': '9.239'},
 {'position': '538', 'player_name': 'Darkdragon', 'points': '8.475'},
 {'position': '539', 'player_name': 'nimrat', 'points': '8.391'},
 {'position': '540', 'player_name': '[YorkCore] Neo', 'points': '7.033'},
 {'position': '541', 'player_name': 'Katniss95', 'points': '7.002'},
 {'position': '542', 'player_name': 'Lieutenant Dorado', 'points': '6.330'},
 {'position': '543', 'player_name': 'Captain Asteroid', 'points': '6.179'},
 {'position': '544', 'player_name': 'Procurator Matter', 'points': '6.044'},
 {'position': '545', 'player_name': 'Black Dog', 'points': '5.960'},
 {'position': '546', 'player_name': 'Renegade Sattelite', 'points': '5.833'},
 {'position': '547', 'player_name': 'Bandit Zagadra', 'points': '5.320'},
 {'position': '548', 'player_name': 'Celestial Fury', 'points': '5.187'},
 {'position': '549', 'player_name': 'President Epsilon', 'points': '4.987'},
 {'position': '550', 'player_name': 'Marshal Artemis', 'points': '4.871'},
 {'position': '551', 'player_name': 'Engineer Fay', 'points': '4.373'},
 {'position': '552', 'player_name': 'Utnapishtim', 'points': '4.341'},
 {'position': '553', 'player_name': 'Stadtholder Rigel', 'points': '3.845'},
 {'position': '554', 'player_name': 'Newton', 'points': '3.818'},
 {'position': '555', 'player_name': 'Engineer Zenith', 'points': '3.797'},
 {'position': '556', 'player_name': 'MrGame', 'points': '3.703'},
 {'position': '557', 'player_name': 'Governor Cupid', 'points': '3.567'},
 {'position': '558', 'player_name': 'Proconsul Cosmo', 'points': '3.528'},
 {'position': '559', 'player_name': 'Bravo_03', 'points': '3.459'},
 {'position': '560', 'player_name': 'Makhundsmester', 'points': '3.457'},
 {'position': '561', 'player_name': 'Vice Eagle', 'points': '3.430'},
 {'position': '562', 'player_name': 'Constable Pegasus', 'points': '3.420'},
 {'position': '563', 'player_name': 'Bandit Eridanus', 'points': '3.361'},
 {'position': '564', 'player_name': 'Admiral Eridanus', 'points': '3.316'},
 {'position': '565', 'player_name': 'Marshal Ranger', 'points': '3.101'},
 {'position': '566', 'player_name': 'Oztk', 'points': '2.902'},
 {'position': '567', 'player_name': 'Director Stardust', 'points': '2.796'},
 {'position': '568', 'player_name': 'Stadtholder Ceti', 'points': '2.765'},
 {'position': '569', 'player_name': '[MME] Sovereign', 'points': '2.515'},
 {'position': '570', 'player_name': 'NO3KAH', 'points': '2.463'},
 {'position': '571', 'player_name': 'Lord Spica', 'points': '2.406'},
 {'position': '572', 'player_name': '[F K', 'points': '2.241'},
 {'position': '573', 'player_name': 'Siegmeyer', 'points': '2.238'},
 {'position': '574', 'player_name': 'Constable Phobos', 'points': '1.942'},
 {'position': '575', 'player_name': 'Amadra', 'points': '1.844'},
 {'position': '576', 'player_name': 'BLURAIDER', 'points': '1.778'},
 {'position': '577', 'player_name': 'Senator Ganimed', 'points': '1.563'},
 {'position': '578', 'player_name': '[ACT] KotPali', 'points': '1.460'},
 {'position': '579', 'player_name': 'Joker', 'points': '1.295'},
 {'position': '580', 'player_name': 'Emperor Zenith', 'points': '1.278'},
 {'position': '581', 'player_name': 'eMic127', 'points': '1.277'},
 {'position': '582', 'player_name': 'Silver', 'points': '1.234'},
 {'position': '583', 'player_name': 'Tarahen', 'points': '1.131'},
 {'position': '584', 'player_name': 'Chief Probe', 'points': '1.069'},
 {'position': '585', 'player_name': 'Czar Meridian', 'points': '1.051'},
 {'position': '586', 'player_name': 'Senator Twighlight', 'points': '998'},
 {'position': '587', 'player_name': 'Savage Spartan', 'points': '952'},
 {'position': '588', 'player_name': 'Vice Omega', 'points': '897'},
 {'position': '589', 'player_name': 'Lilith752', 'points': '893'},
 {'position': '590', 'player_name': 'Emperor Corvus', 'points': '855'},
 {'position': '591', 'player_name': 'Commodore Stingray', 'points': '822'},
 {'position': '592', 'player_name': '[Doge] ToTheMoon', 'points': '755'},
 {'position': '593', 'player_name': 'Marshal Beid', 'points': '524'},
 {'position': '594', 'player_name': 'Senator Cassini', 'points': '434'},
 {'position': '595', 'player_name': 'Governor Celestial', 'points': '246'},
 {'position': '596', 'player_name': 'Chief Amos', 'points': '240'},
 {'position': '597', 'player_name': 'moldy', 'points': '227'},
 {'position': '598', 'player_name': 'Lieutenant Gamma', 'points': '222'},
 {'position': '599', 'player_name': 'Commodore Genesis', 'points': '183'},
 {'position': '600', 'player_name': 'Consul Ultraviolet', 'points': '175'}]
```

I've tested this script using firefox driver.